# Error installing devtools, dplyr,ggplot2 on R-devel 3.4.0 on Windows

Tags: gcc, devtools, r-package

I will submitting my package to CRAN. I have already built with R 3.2.4 and I now am trying to build on R-devel 3.4.0 before submitting to CRAN as required. I am having problems installing packages. I have installed Rtools33.exe for Windows. But I get an errors when installing the following packages - devtools, dplyr, ggplot2 etc. Here are the errors for devtools

```
 > install.packages("devtools")
   also installing the dependencies ‘mime’, ‘openssl’, ‘httr’, ‘memoise’, ‘digest’, ‘jsonlite’, ‘git2r’
 * installing *source* package 'mime' ...
   ** package 'mime' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  ** libs

        *** arch - i386
    d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/software/R/R- DEVE~1/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O3  -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c rawmatch.c -o rawmatch.o
    d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/mingw_32/bin/gcc: not found
   make: *** [rawmatch.o] Error 127
 Warning: running command 'make -f "C:/software/R/R-DEVE~1/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/software/R/R-DEVE~1/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB="mime.dll" OBJECTS="rawmatch.o"' had status 2
        ERROR: compilation failed for package 'mime'
 * removing 'C:/software/R/R-devel-Mar30/library/mime'
    Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/software/R/R-DEVE~1/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l        "C:\software\R\R-devel-Mar30\library" C:\Users\Ganesh\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpq4DzNw/downloaded_packages/mime_0.4.tar.gz' had status 1
   Warning in install.packages :
   installation of package ‘mime’ had non-zero exit status
 * installing *source* package 'openssl' ...
  ** package 'openssl' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs

 *** arch - i386
 "C:/software/R/R-DEVE~1/bin/i386/Rscript.exe" "../tools/winlibs.R"
 d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/software/R/R-DEVE~1/include" -DNDEBUG -I../windows/openssl-1.0.2d/include    -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c win32/ipv6.c -o win32/ipv6.o
    d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/mingw_32/bin/gcc: not found
  make: *** [win32/ipv6.o] Error 127
       Warning: running command 'make -f "Makevars.win" -f "C:/software/R/R-  DEVE~1/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/software/R/R-DEVE~1/share/make/winshlib.mk"   SHLIB="openssl.dll" OBJECTS="aes.o base64.o bignum.o cert.o envelope.o error.o hash.o info.o keygen.o onload.o openssh.o rand.o read.o rsa.o signing.o ssl.o stream.o write.o"' had status 2
   ERROR: compilation failed for package 'openssl'
      * removing 'C:/software/R/R-devel-Mar30/library/openssl'
    Warning in install.packages :
   running command '"C:/software/R/R-DEVE~1/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l            "C:\software\R\R-devel-Mar30\library" C:\Users\Ganesh\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpq4DzNw/downloaded_packages/openssl_0.9.2.tar.gz' had status 1
  Warning in install.packages :
 installation of package ‘openssl’ had non-zero exit status
 * installing *source* package 'digest' ...
 ** package 'digest' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
```

Similar errors regarding gcc occurs. Please let me know what needs to be done

Comment: Same here: 

* installing *source* package 'DescTools' ...
** libs
d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-devel/include" -DNDEBUG    -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-devel/library/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-devel/library/BH/include" -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c ADinf.c -o ADinf.o

d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/mingw_64/bin/gcc: not found

Comment: @Andri you could build on alpha R3.3.0 instead of R 3.4.0 as per CRAN

Comment: Yes no problem with prior versions. It obviously has to do with a fixed path for the compiler on drive d. I would not know how to change that... Hope they will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Since R 3.4.0 is still in early development stages the errors are expected. This is the response I got from CRAN. As of now we need to build on a more stable R 3.3.0